# cracking a word code

Tags: puzzle

edited my word code -- Of course everyone may boo this problem saying its not math enough and more of a 'riddle me this' type question. But I think it's math very much so as I got as far as to eliminate the letters from ones not in common with the given words now I got stuck but will try more later and edit. Please help with giving a method to solve it.the secret word is a certain 12 letter word which consists of exactly one letter from each pair below . for example if the letter D appears then its partner H does not . when the secret word is spelled correctly the unused letter partners appear in alphabetical order .the pairs are A/F B/E C/X D/H G/Q I/O J/U K/S L/R M/T N/P and V/Y also the secret word has the same number of letters in common with the words: CHROME FLICK FORMAT  BEG PROBLEM . find the secret word based on this information

Comment: Your edit confused me. I am not sure what you are alluding to with `also the secret word has the same number of letters in common with the words: CHROME FLICK FORMAT BEG PROBLEM.`

Comment: There are 4096 12-letters words that satisfy the given constraints, from *badinglkmjcv* to *xhbautpiglky*.  The only one that one could find in a dictionary is *exhaustingly*, as pointed out by @MBorg.

Comment: MBorg thats what I emailed the teacher that posed this problem! as a pow ( problem of week )

Answer (score 1):

Exhaustingly is the word

First I obtained all 12-length words that comprise of the 24 letters in your riddle by  a word finder. i.e. all 26 letters of the alphabet except for W and Z. I then removed any word that had both or neither of the letters A and F. I repeated the step, removing words with both or neither of the letters B and E. I then removed words with both or neither of C or X, and so on. After I checked all letters, exhaustingly was the only word remaining.

I carried out the process of searching for the letters using SAS, with this code:

```
* insert words into a data set;
data wordlist;
input words $12.;
datalines;
absorptively
Adjunctively
adsorptively
Ambidextrous
amphicyrtous
amylodextrin
backpointers
Bankruptcies
blackfigured
blackshirted
Blastodermic
bleachground
blepharoncus
Blockheadism
Bluestocking
bounderishly
brachylogies
brachypodine
Breastplough
candleshrift
Celidography
cephalodymus
chiastoneury
Chirogymnast
chlorguanide
Clypeastroid
cogitabundly
combustively
compulsative
configurable
configurated
considerably
consumptible
countervails
cryptomnesia
culteranismo
daemonurgist
dasyproctine
declinograph
demographics
demographist
demonstrably
deutonymphal
deutoplasmic
discountable
discoverably
discrepantly
disculpatory
dismountable
disreputably
disulphonate
doughfaceism
dumbstricken
edulcorating
eurygnathism
exclusionary
exculpations
exhaustingly
expurgations
farsightedly
flexographic
flourishment
fractonimbus
fructokinase
fuglemanship
fuscohyaline
gastroplenic
glandiferous
glanditerous
goldsmithery
gymnoblastic
headstrongly
hernioplasty
hydatigenous
hydrobiplane
hydrocauline
hydroclimate
hydrosalpinx
hydrosulfate
hydrosulfite
hyperstoical
hypnotisable
hypodermatic
hypogastrium
imponderably
importunable
incomputable
incomputably
Involucrated
juxtapyloric
kinetography
lexicography
locksmithery
loudspeaking
mackintoshed
malnourished
mendaciously
metrosalpinx
misconjugate
multipronged
musicography
myelographic
neuroblastic
neuroplasmic
outfieldsman
outsparkling
outspreading
overhumanity
overmatching
overstudying
oxycephalism
pachydermous
packinghouse
parenchymous
perodactylus
persuadingly
pervulgation
phytalbumose
placentiform
polycentrism
polysemantic
postbrachium
praecognitum
preadjusting
precombating
prefungoidal
productively
projectingly
promuscidate
pseudobinary
Pseudobranch
pseudomantic
pseudorganic
pseudotribal
psychoneural
puborectalis
pulmogastric
pyroglutamic
Pyromagnetic
pyroxmangite
quebrachitol
Questionably
quodlibetary
remodulating
shopbreaking
slaughterdom
Smotheringly
spermoviduct
splaymouthed
stampedingly
Stenographic
stickhandler
stylographic
subarytenoid
subcheliform
subcordately
subformative
subjectional
subnormality
sulfocyanide
sulfohydrate
sulphonamide
sulphovinate
supercombing
supernotably
supraglenoid
symblepharon
symbranchoid
thunderclaps
ticklenburgs
Triadelphous
tricephalous
turbomachine
tympanichord
unabortively
unabsorptive
unadoptively
uncompatible
uncompatibly
uncomplexity
uncreditably
unepistolary
unfarsighted
unforgivable
unforgivably
unformalised
unformidable
unformidably
unfreakishly
Unhospitable
unhospitably
unhysterical
unimprovable
unimprovably
unimprovedly
unmetaphysic
unmethodical
unmistakedly
Unperishably
unphlegmatic
unpostmarked
unpredicably
unproclaimed
unprofitable
unprofitably
unprovidable
unprovisedly
unsportively
upholstering
Vehiculatory
Voluntaryism
xiphosternum
Xylophagides
;
run;

data wordlist_1;
set wordlist;
if find(words, "a") = 0 AND find(words, "f") = 0 then delete; * if neither a or f then delete;
if find(words, "a") ^= 0 AND find(words, "f") ^= 0 then delete; * if both a and f then delete;
run;

data wordlist_2;
set wordlist_1;
if find(words, "b") = 0 AND find(words, "e") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "b") ^= 0 AND find(words, "e") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_3;
set wordlist_2;
if find(words, "c") = 0 AND find(words, "x") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "c") ^= 0 AND find(words, "x") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_4;
set wordlist_3;
if find(words, "d") = 0 AND find(words, "h") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "d") ^= 0 AND find(words, "h") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_5;
set wordlist_4;
if find(words, "g") = 0 AND find(words, "q") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "g") ^= 0 AND find(words, "q") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_6;
set wordlist_5;
if find(words, "i") = 0 AND find(words, "o") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "i") ^= 0 AND find(words, "o") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_7;
set wordlist_6;
if find(words, "j") = 0 AND find(words, "u") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "j") ^= 0 AND find(words, "u") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_8;
set wordlist_7;
if find(words, "k") = 0 AND find(words, "s") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "k") ^= 0 AND find(words, "s") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_9;
set wordlist_8;
if find(words, "l") = 0 AND find(words, "r") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "l") ^= 0 AND find(words, "r") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_10;
set wordlist_9;
if find(words, "m") = 0 AND find(words, "t") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "m") ^= 0 AND find(words, "t") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_11;
set wordlist_10;
if find(words, "n") = 0 AND find(words, "p") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "n") ^= 0 AND find(words, "p") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

data wordlist_12;
set wordlist_11;
if find(words, "v") = 0 AND find(words, "y") = 0 then delete;
if find(words, "v") ^= 0 AND find(words, "y") ^= 0 then delete;
run;

proc print data = wordlist_12;
run;
```

Comment: Interestingly, the requirement that the partner letters form an increasing sequence is not needed to thin your list down to the one word "exhaustingly."